# Error Installing Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm getting following error both on web install or directly using the ISO image downloaded. how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: what happens if you click on the link "problems"

Comment: Nothing happening. It simply displayed in blue. I tried with both ISO downloaded and webinstall. but the same result

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually create the directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0, then run the install.  It seems the beta installer doesn't create the directory for some reason.